# My battery icon has x in it

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hardware, battery

My MacBook Pro 15" battery has a black X in the battery icon and the indicator lights on the side do not light up when button is pressed. What could be the problem? It runs fine when plugged in

Comment: Most probably, the battery has died. Which year model is it?

Answer (score 5):

Most likely the battery has died or is no longer being recognized by the system. To verify it is not the latter Apple has a KB article that will help with [resetting the SMC.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295)

If it is the former it's time to replace the battery. If you are under warranty take it to a nearby Apple store. If not they can still do the repair but it will cost you. Depending on the model you have replacing the battery can be trivially easy (open the latches on the bottom and pop out the battery) to "just give up and cry yourself to sleep."

More info on your make and model would [help us determine](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59606/battery-warning-service-battery-goes-away-by-itself) where your hardware falls in that spectrum and [how many cycles you might expect on your battery before it disconnects itself](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/94772/battery-indicator-is-showing-service-battery-notification) like you have noticed.

Answer (score 1):

This means your MacBook does not recognise the battery. Maybe it's not installed properly?

https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18598?locale=en_US

Comment: Its a 2011 macbook pro i7, i replaced the battery with a new one but it was also not detected. i suspect its the battery meter on left side because this it does not light up, not even when you connect the charger

Answer (score 0):

If the battery icon in the menu bar contains an X, either your Mac does not recognise the battery or the battery is not properly installed in your portable Mac.

- If a battery is fully charged, but you still see an X: Your Mac may not recognise the battery. After you plug in your Mac and let the battery charge for five minutes, the battery should be recognised.
  Your battery can become fully drained if you use your Mac unplugged until it puts itself to sleep or if you leave it in sleep mode for an extended period.
- If your computer has an accessible battery: If you can access the battery, remove it, then reinstall it. Refer to the manual that came with your Mac for more information about properly installing the battery.

If the battery icon in the menu bar still has an X in it, your Mac may need to be serviced.